# Move Genesis Single Page/Single Post Title

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, customization, conditional-tags, genesis-theme-framework

Im not sure on how to do this .. But what i want to do is .

1. Move the Page/Single Post Page title.
2. Remove the title for Homepage only.
3. Keep the titles of my posts. (Loop page) or (Blog Page)

Here's what i have:

```
    remove_action('genesis_post_title', 'genesis_do_post_title');
    add_action ('genesis_after_header','title_slider');
        function title_slider() {
            if (is_page('Home')) {
                remove_action('genesis_after_header', 'genesis_do_post_title');
            } 

            if (is_page() || is_single()){
            echo "<div class='main-title-bg'>";
            the_title( '<h1>', '</h1>' );
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
```

It did move the single post / page titles, also it did remove the title in the Homepage..

But When i check my BLOG page, the titles are not there...

Here's the structure i want for the BLOG page (A typical normal blog page structure)

---

(logo)(menus)
**BLOG PAGE TITLE**

---

Post title here
posted by: meh etc.
Content here.. 
readmore...

---

Post title here
posted by: meh etc.
Content here.. 
readmore...

---

Post title here
posted by: meh etc.
Content here.. 
readmore...

---

I hope everything is clear! Thanks guys!

Comment: How is your home page setup? Check the Settings > Reading option page in the Admin. It looks like you are using a static home page. While this is possible in Genesis, most of its child themes are specifically set up for use with home (and blog) pages that are not static. Using a static front page is often left untested by the theme author.

Comment: Front page displays: `Front page: Home <-- Page`    `Posts page: Blog <-- Page`

Comment: I need this kind of setup.. even i remove that setup and change it to latest posts. still the titles for the blogs doesn't show

Comment: Okay. Next question: What is the name of the Blog page, what is its page ID and which Page Template is assigned to it? You can find that information in the Blog page editor in the admin.

Comment: Hi Charles, the name of the blog page is 'Cases' page ID is 15 it is using the default template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_124609_remove_titles' );
/**
 * Move or remove some post titles.
 */
function wpse_124609_remove_titles() {

    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        remove_action( 'genesis_post_title', 'genesis_do_post_title' );

    } else if ( is_page() || is_single() ) {
        remove_action( 'genesis_post_title', 'genesis_do_post_title' );
        add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'title_slider' );
    }
}

/**
 * Add Title Slider to some post titles.
 */
function title_slider() {
    echo "<div class='main-title-bg'>";
    the_title( '<h1>', '</h1>' );
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: You really rock men!!!